# One-Dimensional Jump-Diffusion Ito’s Formula

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes

Let, $N_t$ be a Poisson process and let $X_t$ solve the SDE $d{X_t}=a_t dt +J_t dN_t$. Then, what is the correct Ito´s fórmula:

i)$df(t,X_t)=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}a_t)dt + (f(t, X_t+J_t)-f(t,X_t))dN_t$

or

ii)$df(t,X_t)=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} a_t)dt + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}J_t )dN_t$

I have seen both of the in literature, but I do not know if one of them is incorrect or  they are equivelent.

Thank you :)

Comment: There is something wrong with your small $a$ and capital $A$

Comment: Thanks! I ve fixed it :) Do you know if they seem to bee the same formula or something is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that (i) is correct, I have never seen (ii) in the literature.

Comment: Does someone know the demostration of i? I`m quite sure they must be equivalent or there must be a small error,

Comment: @Edin_91 The following is deliberately phrased sketchily for purposes of intuition. When $N$ changes, it changes by a finite amount instantaneously. It does not change by an infinitesimal amount from one moment to the next. That means that although the $dN_t$ term arises through the dependence of $f$ on $x$, you have to add up all the changes in $f$ as the $x$ argument changes from $X_t$ to $X_t+J_t$, not as $x$ changes from one number to an infinitely close number.

Comment: @Edin_91 For illustration, consider an $f$ which depends only on $x$ and is zero on $[-1/2,1/2]$ and positive elsewhere. Suppose $X_0=0,a_t \equiv 0,J_t \equiv 1$. Then your second form would not change $f$ at the first jump, but $f$ clearly does change at the first jump (it should go to $f(1)$).

Comment: Thank yoy Ian. You mean, then, that (i) is correct and (ii) is not. Do you?

Comment: @Edin_91 That's right.

Comment: And do you know how to demonstrate it?

Comment: It is just the definition of the derivative except at the points where $N$ jumps. Where you have a jump, suppose $N$ jumps by some amount $\Delta N$ at time $t$. Then $X$ jumps by $J_t \Delta N$ at time $t$. Hence $f$ jumps by $f(t,X_t+J_t\Delta N)-f(t,X_t)$ at time $t$ (assuming here that $f \in C^1$). There is only a minor technical issue, which is that you need to be sure that the jumps are isolated from one another with probability $1$ in order to do the differentiation at the remaining points. But this is routine.

Comment: Yes, I do know that because $N_t$ is a poisson process and two jumps do not ocurr at the same tine (if you are referring to this).

Comment: I undernstand what you have already explained.However I don´t know whot to achieve $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}a_t)dt$ and combine with the other.

Comment: Do you understand my problem?

Comment: @Edin_91 Again you're just differentiating classically at the times when $N$ does not jump. When $N$ does jump the other term doesn't matter, as it is infinitesimally small while the other term is of finite size. You can make this precise with, for instance, distribution theory if you want, but I don't see what it buys you.

Comment: So,when $N$ doesn`t jump $dX_t=a_t dt$ and $d(f(t,x))= \frac{\partial f }{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial f }{\partial x}dx = \frac{\partial f }{\partial t}dt +  \frac{\partial f }{\partial x}a_t dt $ Is this right? And can I can do this when $dX_t = a_t dt + J_t d_{N_t}$ and obtain (ii)?